# JS async/await populating array with links then downloading once array is populated

Tags: javascript, api, promise, async-await

I know it's been asked multiple times but I'm still unable to find a solution to my particular problem. Basically as per the title, I have written a function `getLinks()` that would populate a global array `links` through api calls from [SG Gov Traffic Data API](https://data.gov.sg/dataset/traffic-images?view_id=a0e54baf-6ef7-4bca-9aa2-8c6ca37a0a0e&resource_id=e127e29a-bd48-47e2-a0a7-e89ce31f10c7).

The problem arises when I try to download the images via function `getImages()` as this function needs to wait for the `links` array to be populated before running. I can't seem to get the logic right for the sequential execution of the functions.

Full code below. Thanks in advance for any pointers!

```js
var fs = require('fs'),
    request = require('request');

// Download individual content
function download(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('training/' + filename)).on('close', callback);
  });
};

// Get image links from API
var links =[];

function two(n){
    return n > 9 ? "" + n: "0" + n;
}

async function getLinks() {
  links = []; // Clear the links array
  for(i = 1; i < 30; i++) { // Loop through 30 days, chosen month is Dec 2018
    for(j = 0; j < 24; j++) { // Loop through 24 hours each day
      request('https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/traffic-images?date_time=2018-12-' + two(i) + 'T' + two(j) + '%3A00%3A00', function(error, response, body) {
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);
          links.push(parsedData.items[0]["cameras"][0]["image"].toString())
        } else {
          console.log(error)
        }
      })
    }
  }
  return;
}

// Scrape and download to directory
async function getImages() {
  await getLinks();
  for( i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    download(links[i], i, function(){});
  }
}

getImages();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getLinks returns before it is resolved,

maybe wrap a promise around the request call push those into an array and then return promise.all(asyncArray)

but currently its just

```
async function getImages() {
  await undefined //getLinks();
  for( i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    download(links[i], i, function(){});
  }
}
```

e.g:

```
async function getLinks() {
    links = []; // Clear the links array
    let asyncs = []
    for(i = 1; i < 30; i++) { // Loop through 30 days, chosen month is Dec 2018
      for(j = 0; j < 24; j++) { // Loop through 24 hours each day
        asyncs.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request('https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/traffic-images?date_time=2018-12-' + two(i) + 'T' + two(j) + '%3A00%3A00', function(error, response, body) {
            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);
                links.push(parsedData.items[0]["cameras"][0]["image"].toString())
                resolve(parsedData.items[0]["cameras"][0]["image"].toString())
            } else {
                console.log(error)
                //reject(error)
            }
            })
        }))
      }
    }
    return Promise.all(asyncs)
  }

async function getImages() {
  let _links = await getLinks();
  for( i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    download(links[i], i, function(){});
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Yeah, it works perfectly now, guess I still need to get to know async/await better. :)